# Python regex capture text between ":" and ". " (dot followed by whitespace)

Tags: python, regex

I have some pieces of text like this:

```
GAEDS030, GAEDS031, GAEDS032 : Problem reported in a https://twikiae.myweb.es
/twiki/bin/view/Grid/ActFeb2011 previous entry has been observed in another disk server
that was under a stress test (gaeds034). We have contacted technical service at LSI and 
they have suggested us to update to a brand new firmware (!FE9X 4.10.00.021). After a new
test period if seems that raid card does not reset under heavy load as in the past. So it
has been upgraded every card of this branch (gaeds030-gaeds034)
```

Some of them don't have the colon.

Now I'm using this regex to capture text after first `:` and before first `.`

```
    re.search(':([^\.]*)(\.)*', description)
```

and this when it doesn't have `:`

```
    re.search('((.*)(?!\. ))', description)
```

As you can see, I have problem when there are URLs, IPs, etc so I'd like to capture text after `:` before `.` (dot followed by whitespace) instead.

I've tried white negated set, but it doesn't allow to use them with groups.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The actual output is: `Problem reported in a https://twikiae` but I'd like to get `Problem reported in a https://twikiae.myweb.es
/twiki/bin/view/Grid/ActFeb2011 previous entry has been observed in another disk server that was under a stress test (gaeds034)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
:\s*(.*?)\.\s
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yU4rV3/2).

Answer (score 0):

Because of newline characters present in your input, it's better to use [DOTALL modifier `(?s)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)  to make dot to match even newline characters also. So that the match would be on multiple lines.

```
(?<=:\s).*?(?=\.\s)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vF9jV6/2)

```
>>> s = """GAEDS030, GAEDS031, GAEDS032 : Problem reported in a https://twikiae.myweb.es
... /twiki/bin/view/Grid/ActFeb2011 previous entry has been observed in another disk server
... that was under a stress test (gaeds034). We have contacted technical service at LSI and 
... they have suggested us to update to a brand new firmware (!FE9X 4.10.00.021). After a new
... test period if seems that raid card does not reset under heavy load as in the past. So it
... has been upgraded every card of this branch (gaeds030-gaeds034)"""
>>> re.search(r'(?s)(?<=:\s).*?(?=\.\s)', s).group()
'Problem reported in a https://twikiae.myweb.es\n/twiki/bin/view/Grid/ActFeb2011 previous entry has been observed in another disk server\nthat was under a stress test (gaeds034)'
>>> m = re.search(r'(?s)(?<=:\s).*?(?=\.\s)', s).group()
>>> print m
Problem reported in a https://twikiae.myweb.es
/twiki/bin/view/Grid/ActFeb2011 previous entry has been observed in another disk server
that was under a stress test (gaeds034)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:(.*?)(?=\.\s)
```

Try this.See demo.use flags `s` or `DOTALL` in python.

http://regex101.com/r/hS3dT7/2